# Scala Stream Contiually get rid of var

Tags: scala, stream

I'm trying to generate an infinite list of dates by substracting one month from the current date, i want to do this using Streams.

Here's what i've done so far :

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate

var date = new LocalDate("2022-05-24")
val dateSeq = Seq(date)
val allDates = dateSeq.toStream ++ Stream.continually(dateSeq)
  .flatMap(ticks => ticks.map(_ => {
    date = date.minusMonths(1)
    date
  }))
allDates.take(5).toList
```

My problem is that im using a var to decrement the current date by a month each time.

Is there any way to get rid of that `var` ?

Comment: Why `Stream` are you on `2.12`? Can you upgrade to `2.13` an use `LazyList` instead?

Comment: Im on 2.11.12 actually. This is a simplified version of a problem that i'm facing at work and we use 2.11.12 on this particular project.
But yeah, i could definitely upgrade to 2.13

Comment: If you can upgrade then I would recommend doing that, you can solve this problem pretty easily using `LazyList.unfold`

Comment: Alright, is there really no way to solve this using `Stream` ?

Comment: Well, you may create an infinite stream of continually the same date then zip it with an infinite stream from `0` to inifite and then `map` to compute the new date. There is probably also a way similar to the Fibonacci sequence example in the docs.

Comment: Thanks, can u copy/paste this as an answer so i can accept it ?

Comment: Feel free to add the working code as your own answer and I will happily upvote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want `.iterate` rather than `.continually`:

```
    vall allDates = Stream.iterate(LocalDate.now) { _.minusMonth(1) }
```

Comment: `def iterate[A](start: A)(f: A => A): Stream[A] = cons(start, iterate(f(start))(f))` So I must pass a function `f: A => A`. Is there any workaround to pass a function `f: A => B` ?

Comment: @Ares this one is `LocalDate => LocalDate`. It can't really be `A => B` because both input and output are elements of the stream (previous and next), so they can't have different types

Answer (score 1):

Using @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez  solution:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate

val numberOfMonthsBack = 5
val date = new LocalDate("2022-05-24")
val dateSeq = Seq(date)
val allDates = dateSeq.toStream ++ Stream.continually(dateSeq)
  .zip(Stream.from(1))
  .flatMap(ticks => 
    ticks._1.map(x => x.minusMonths(ticks._2))
  )
allDates
  .take(numberOfMonthsBack).toList
```